# Disable buttons on GUI in Swing

Tags: java, swing, selenium-webdriver, jbutton

I have buttons on a GUI that execute tests when clicked on in Selenium. They can only be run serially and are currently added to `EventQueue`. I would like it so that if a button is clicked on and a test is executed, then it will disable the other buttons so that other tests cannot be added to a queue.

Currently a button looks like:

```
    Test1 = new JButton("Test1 ");
    Test1.setLocation(290, 30);
    Test1.setSize(120, 30);
    Test1.addActionListener(this);
    Test1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            if (Test1.isEnabled()) {
                Test1.setEnabled(false);
                errorLabel.setText("");
                service.submit(()->{
                    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
                        errorMessageDisplay(result);
                        Test1.setEnabled(true);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(Test1);
```

I have used the `EventQueue` as it allows me to reset update Pass/Fail error messages on the GUI.

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? If you don't need the disabled effect, i.e. if it would be ok for a button to be clickable but the action doing nothing, you could use a shared semaphore (e.g. a lock object).

Comment: You should never use MouseListeners in this way. This is what ActionListeners are for. For one, MouseListeners ignore if a button is disabled, while ActionListeners do not.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Give me some feedback so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Hi, I am currently trying to implement it, I have like 15 buttons on the GUI so I will I need to set these all to DISABLED by default?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `ActionListener` to your button. What's even more important, you should use naming conventions what also means that your objects' names should start with a small letter. Capital letters are reserved for Classes and static fields (all upper case). The following code adds an `ActionListener` to your `JButton` and disables it after clicked. If it's not what you're looking for, I'll add another version in a moment.

```
test1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            test1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

In case, you want to keep the *state* of your button, but don't disable it, the following code might be a solution:

```
private final static String ENABLED = "ENABLED";
private final static String DISABLED = "DISABLED";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<JButton, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    JButton test1 = new JButton();
    map.put(test1, ENABLED);
    test1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (map.get(test1).equals(ENABLED)) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something else. I'll enable.
                map.remove(test1);
                map.put(test1, ENABLED);
            }
        }
    });

}
```