# Cannot utilize same button twice in Swing

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I have created a GUI in Java using Swing that for some reason will not let me utilize the action of the same JButton twice.

Here is the code:

```
    test1 = new JButton("test1 ");
    test1.setLocation(290, 70);
    test1.setSize(120, 30);
    test1.addActionListener(this);
    test1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            if (test1.isEnabled()) {
                errorLabel.setText("");
                service.submit(()->{
                    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
                        errorMessageDisplay(result);
                        test1.setEnabled(true);
                    });
                });

            }
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(test1);
```

This executes a Selenium script, and after test completion I have to restart the GUI in order to make use of the same action again. Let it be known that I have other buttons; such as test2, test3, etc. which I am able to use after test1 has completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable buttons on GUI in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850620/disable-buttons-on-gui-in-swing)

Comment: There's no need to ask the same question twice.

Comment: This is not the same question, I am trying to understand why I cannot utilize the same button twice. That other question is regarding disabling buttons... I am not sure where you are coming from?

Comment: I think the key is in the `service.submit` method... is it enqueued? maybe a second execution is not happening because the first one prevents it in some way

Comment: Why did you ignore the advice offered on your first question? It makes me wonder if there is any *point* to offering further advice, and others might think the same thing..

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have not ignored the advice and am currently still trying to implement the recommended the solutions. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson: the solution is to [ask the same question yet again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862835/cannot-run-already-executed-scripts-via-swing). Looks like yet another [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem).

Answer (score 1):

In your MouseListener handler, you have

```
        if (test1.isEnabled()) {
            test1.setEnabled(false);
```

So the first time it is enabled, but then you are disabling the button. This is why you can only click it once

Comment: Even with the 2nd line 'test1.setEnabled(false);' removed it still does not allow me to use the same button twice

Answer (score 0):

The code that re-enables the button is only added to the event queue only after all the process is completed (the method runClasses is completed). I think you are trying to click it before that happens.

Comment: Hmmm, it could be, however I am 100% sure the runClasses method is completed as I get it to render a message on the screen to show test completion

Comment: And the anonymous method that you pass to invokeLater? Is it executed? I'd try to add a log trace there to check that